# complexity of functions in C

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
int f1(int N) {
    int Sum, i, j, k;
    Sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++)    
                Sum++;
    return Sum;
}

int f2(int N) {
    int Sum, i, j;
    Sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            Sum += j * N;
    return Sum;
}
```

What are the complexities of `f1` and `f2`?

I have no idea about the complexity of `f1` and I think the complexity of `f2` should be **O(1)** since the number of iterations is constant. It is correct?

Comment: `f2`is of course O(1).

Comment: `f1` is `O(N^5)`

Comment: @IanAbbott Why f1 is O(N^4)?

Comment: @RLee, sorry, I was wrong. It is indeed O(N^5) (O(N*(N^2)*(N^2))).

Answer (score 6):

Your first function has the complexity O(N^(1+2+2)) = O(N^5).

In the first loop i goes from 0 on N, the second one j loops over a limit that depends on N^2 and in the 3rd one k loops on an interval whose size depends on N^2 as well.

The function F2 is constant time, so O(1) because the loops do not have any degree of liberty.

This kind of stuff is studied in the courses of algorithms at the topic "complexity".

There is also another kind of measurement of complexity of algorithms, based on [omega-notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation).

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of `f1` is in O(n^5) since

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++) //i has a upper bound of n 
    for(j=0; j<i*i; j++) //j has a upper bound of i^2, which itself has the upper bound of n, so this is n^2
        for(k=0; k<j; k++) //k has a upper bound of j, which is n^2  
            Sum++; //constant
```

So the complete upper bound is n * n^2 * n^2 which is n^5 so `f1` is in O(n^5).

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //upper bound of 10 so in O(10) which is in O(1)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) //upper bound of i so also O(1)
        Sum += j * N; //N is just a integer here, and multiplication is a constant operation independent of the size of N, so also O(1)
```

So `f2` is in O(1*1*1) which is simply O(1).
Note all assignments and declarations are also constant.

BTW since `Sum++` has no side effects and with the according loops develops a series we know a solution for (math yay), a programmer or optimal compiler optimiser could reduce `f1` to a constant program using the gaussian sum formula `(n*n+n) / 2`, so sum could be just calculated by something like `(N*N + N ) / 2 * (N*N*N*N + N*N) / 2) * 2` , however my formula does not consider starting at 0.

Comment: It would be interesting to see which compiler can reduce this theoretical complexity to O(1).

Comment: @chqrlie In the case of a `Sum++` I hope all production grade compiler, but anyhow any reasonable developer would hopefully just `return (N*N + N ) / 2 * (N*N*N*N + N*N) / 2) * 2` (off by one errors not included)

Comment: `gcc` does not seem to reduce the complexity, even at `-O4` and `clang` generates SSE/AVX code that is difficult to follow.

Comment: @chqrlie I guess it's unrealistic that it can optimise it, since it would need a complete symbolic computer algebra system able to solve series and also recognise such loop builds as sums.

Comment: compilers do detect some trivial loops and generate better alternatives. This is done on a case by case basis.

Comment: @chqrlie Still got the problem of detection that those loops together with that += expression constitutes a series, and conclude it's solvable and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation):

## f1:

> > The outer loop runs from 0 to N, the one inside it runs from 0 to i^2 and the last one runs from 0 to j, and inside we only have one operation so we are summing 1. Thus we get:
>
> [image: 1]
>
> > 1+1+1... j times gives 1*j=j, thus we get:
>
> [image: 3]
>
> > Using the rule of [the summation of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) but we replace n (in the Wikipedia article) with i^2 so we get:
>
> [image: 4]
>
> > > The reason for the approximation is because when finding the time complexity of a function and we have the addition of multiple powers we take the highest one. This just makes the math simpler. For example `f(n)=(n^3+n^2+n)=O(n^3)` (supposing that f(n) represents the maximal running time required by the given algorithm depending on the input size n) .
> >
> > And using the formula for the summation of the first N numbers to 4th power we get (look at the note in the end):
>
> [image: 6]

Thus the time complexity for f1 is `O(n^5)`.

## f2:

> > Using the same method we get:
>
> [image: 2]
>
> [image: 8]

But this just gives a constant which doesn't depend on n thus the time complexity for f2 is `O(1)`.

### note:

When we have a summation of the first N numbers that are to the K power, the time complexity of it would be N^(K+1), so you obviously don't need to remember the formula. For example:

> [image: 9]